# Shorten a terminal command into a script

Tags: python

I'm trying to come up with a way to shorten a command that would let me push my configurationfrom a network device to my backup (oxidized)
the full command goeslike this:

```
curl http://192.168.195.57:8888/node/IPofDevicetoPush
```

The command is long and annoying to type when wanting to push the config, so I want to shorten it. In my python script I have as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
IPofDevicetoPush =raw_input("IP or hostname: ")
os.system("curl http://192.168.X.X/node/next/IPofDevicetoPush")
```

What I want to do from the terminal window is something like this:

```
sudo oxs -x Mypush.py IPofDevicetoPush
```

And for IPofDevicetoPush to be "copied" into the script so that the script would run

```
os.system("curl http://192.168.X.X/node/next/IPofDevicetoPush")
```

Comment: Have you tried using sys.argv and inputting the arguments as a string to the script?

Comment: @ZWang No, I'm not familiar with the sys.argv function.

Comment: If you are writing new Python scripts in 2019, you should probably be targeting the currently supported and recommended version of the language, which is Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something very very simple:

```
import sys
import os

os.system("curl http://192.168.X.X/node/next/{}".format(sys.argv[1]))
```

`sys.argv` is a list containing the command line arguments separated by space. `sys.argv[0]` is the script itself, so your argument is `sys.argv[1]`.

Of course you may improve it with all the checks you wish to be sure that the input argument is present an satisfies any requisite you want.

Comment: When running my full command: sudo oxs -x Myscript.py 192.168.55.10, im getting an error saying curl is unrecognized command. I assum I should count space only within the argument and not anything before that

Comment: `sys.argv` splits the command line by spaces. If you type on the command line `test.py one two - three`, `sys.argv` is `['test.py', 'one', 'two', '-', 'three']`. It does not include anything before your script. So if you type `sudo test.py one two - three`, `sys.argv` is the same as before.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Note you should [favor subprocess methods over os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system).

Try something like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from subprocess import call

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Pass an arg.")
    sys.exit(1)

cmd = "curl http://192.168.X.X/node/next/{}".format(sys.argv[1])
sys.exit(call(cmd, shell=True))
```

Comment: `shell=True` is no better than `os.system`. Use `call(["curl", "http://192.168.X.X/node/next/{}".format(sys.argv[1])])`.

Comment: From the `os.system` docs: "The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function." The example that the subprocess docs provide for replacing `os.system` is virtually identical to my answer. As far as the security considerations, OP literally stated he'll be typing this as a shorthand and not accepting input from some other source.